# Icecast stream not loading through AudioContext

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, icecast, audiocontext

I want to create a visual player for an icecast stream in HTML5/JS. I understand you have to use AudioContext to get this working, but I'm having trouble getting it working outside of Chrome, and have no clue why.

- Chrome works ok
- Firefox/Opera does nothing
- IE alerts Web Audio API not supported

See the fiddle below for a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/L37qq/4/

Whats odd is that if I try a local mp3 file everything works fine in Chrome/FF/(Opera?)

I'm fairly sure it has something to do with the line..

```
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
```

Comment: So after a lot of digging I found it was a problem with cross domain policies. Will write up a full answer with my workaround soon

Comment: Hi @FrenchyNZ do you recall what the solution to this was? I think I have the same problem and can't figure it out. Thanks!